# Can aws athena use `parse_datetime` with timezone `CET`?

Tags: sql, timezone, amazon-athena, presto

Can I get the result of
`parse_datetime('2021-11-01 09 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH z') AT TIME ZONE 'CET'` in a more  succinct way? I know the workaround `parse_datetime('2021-11-01 09 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH z') AT TIME ZONE 'CET'` is fine, I am just curious why the `CET` timezone is somehow not included in the function.

The [athena available time zones](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-supported-time-zones.html) do not apply as `parse_datetime` is a java function [presto docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html) and looking at the available [timezone acronyms](http://www.healthstream.com/hlchelp/Administrator/Classes/HLC_Time_Zone_Abbreviations.htm) did not yield any result either.

Some examples.

```sql
SELECT parse_datetime('2021-11-01 09 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH z'), -- this works
       parse_datetime('2021-11-01 09 UTC', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH z') AT TIME ZONE 'CET', -- this works 
       parse_datetime('2021-11-01 09 PST', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH z'), -- this works
       parse_datetime('2021-11-01 09 CET', 'YYYY-MM-dd HH z') -- this does not work
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key is that Java's date parser (which, like you say, is what `parse_datetime` uses) does not support parsing time zone names:

> Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.

(from the Javadoc)

Comment: not sure I understand correctly, but why does it parse things like `UTC` or `PST` but not `CET`?